# How to set up a proxy for email

Tags: email, proxy

My ISP blocks connections on its SMTP server from areas outside its coverage zone. Therefore, I can't send email when I am traveling. I imagine that it would be possible to have some kind of proxy or tunnel program running on my home PC so that I can connect through it in order to send email from abroad.

I am running Windows 7 on both my home PC for the proxy as well as the laptop want to send email abroad on. I am using Outlook 2007 as the email client on the laptop.

Does anyone know of a way to set up such a proxy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a direct answer, but did you try to change the SMTP port to 587 in Outlook? This often gets around this issue.

Or logging onto the ISP's website and send emails direct (not too bad if using exchange or IMAP).

Comment: Thanks, I was able to get it to work by setting the port to 587 and enabling SSL for the SMTP server. For the sake of completeness because it answers my original question, I was able to set up a proxy for the SMTP server by using this program: http://www.aboutmyip.com/AboutMyXApp/SmtpProxy.jsp